# iOS Math: undefined symbols fr architecture arm7

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm getting the following error when trying to use C's `math.h` library:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <math.h>

@interface Filter : NSObject {
    float cutoff;
    float resonance;
    float sampleRate;
    float *f;
    float freq;
    float damp;
}

- (float)filter:(float)input;

@end
```

Can you tell me how I can solve this error? It seems that the `min()` function cannot be compiled to armv7 architectures.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_min", referenced from:
      -[Filter init] in Filter.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: where is min() in your code? And you dont need to import `math.h`

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/ - doesn't seem to contain any min(), but only fmin()

Comment: thanks Anoop and alex, you were both right. I have removed the import of math.h and I'm using fmin. Works all fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS I had to use `fmin()` instead of `min()` as alex purposed. Further, i didn't even need to import `math.h` as Anoop said.

Answer (score 1):

You are linking against a static library that is compiled for i386 or x86-64, in your specific case I think that you have referenced a library that contains min function but is not compiled for armv7 architecture, take a look at your referenced static library .